# How To Create a Multi Page Report Using Ireport 4.1.3?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to create a Multi page report(PDF format) where only some of the pages have dynamic data values to be inserted . While many of the pages have data which is static in nature. How can such a report be created using Ireport. Suggestions, Pointers welcome.

Any suggestions for Good practices would be great to hear.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830420/multiple-pages-in-jrxml-using-ireports-for-multi-page-reports

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any reason why not.

Try

- Markup set to html for text field/static text
- Subreports for complex sections
- Datasets for charts/tables that require their own data query
- Keep together / Start on new page for Bands to control page breaks

These suggestions are only based on what I guess you may have in a long report

Comment: actually I would Like to reframe my question. Do I have to write seperate .JRXML files for each of these reports or the subreports can be part or referenced in some other .jrxml file??

Comment: Reports (and subreports) are seperate .JRXML files but I think you may be want to consider generating different content with the same report (and referenced subreports) based on inputs/data? Look as using parameters to define subreports like this question here [jasper-reports-cover-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366382/jasper-reports-cover-page)